# Notification bar overlays an app. How to fix it?

Tags: java, android

[image]

Notification bar overlays an app.

Here is the AppTheme:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

And the manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acording to the docs:

> By enabling translucent system bars, your layout will fill the area behind the system bars.

So change it value to false.